# Prove that the equation $y^2 = x^5 + 1$ has exactly p solutions modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Condition on p: $ p \ncong 1(mod5) $

I understand that I'm trying to count the number of times that $x^5 + 1$ is a quadratic residue modulo p. I just can't quite figure out exactly why the number of solutions modulo p is equal to p itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ and $p-1$ is not divisible by $5$, exponentiating $x \mapsto x^5$ (and therefore $x \mapsto x^5+1$) is a bijection.

Comment: This answer is a little beyond by grasp. I am a beginning number theory student, and I'm having trouble understanding this. Could you flesh it out a little more?

Comment: If $x^5\equiv y^5\not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $(x z)^5\equiv 1\not \equiv x z$ where $z y\equiv 1$. When $p$ is prime, multiplication mod $p$ on $\{1,..,p-1\}$  is a   group . In a finite group  $G$, if $\exists w\in G :w^5=1\neq  w$  then the number of members of the group is divisible by $ 5$.